# Electron app window does not gain focus when distributed for Mac

Tags: electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

This a strange one for me.  I have an Electron app which works fine when I run it locally. However, when I `npm run dist` it to create a native version, the resulting app fails to take focus when I click on it.  I click on the text field in the window and a flashing cursor shows up however, when I type keystrokes, they go to the window I was in before (e.g. Finder).  This only happens in Mac (Windows works fine) when I'm using a packaged version.

Very perplexing stuff :)

My package.json looks like this (sanitised some names and URLs):

```
{
  "name": "Myapp",
  "productName": "MyApp",
  "version": "0.0.44",
  "description": "MyApp",
  "license": "",
  "repository": "",
  "main": "./main.js",
  "author": {
    "name": "MyApp Ltd.",
    "email": "c@c.com",
    "url": "www.c.com"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=4"
  },
  "electronVersion": "1.8.3",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha",
    "start": "electron .",
    "pack": "build --dir",
    "dist": "build"
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "MyApp",
    "win": {
      "target": "squirrel",
      "icon": "assets/icons/Windows_Icon.ico"
    },
    "squirrelWindows": {
      "loadingGif": "assets/img/installing.gif",
      "iconUrl": "https:/fake-url.com/icon.ico",
      "msi": false
    },
    "dmg": {
      "window": {
        "x": 200,
        "y": 200,
        "width": 537,
        "height": 374
      },
      "icon": "assets/icons/Mac_Icon.icns",
      "background": "assets/img/dmg-background.png"
    },
    "mac": {
      "icon": "assets/icons/Mac_Icon.icns",
      "extendInfo": {
        "LSBackgroundOnly": 1
      }
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "azure-event-hubs": "0.0.4",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.20.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "chokidar": "^1.6.1",
    "download": "^5.0.2",
    "electron-debug": "^0.3.0",
    "electron-is-dev": "^0.3.0",
    "electron-json-storage": "^3.0.4",
    "electron-log": "^2.2.6",
    "electron-positioner": "^3.0.0",
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0",
    "follow-redirects": "^1.2.3",
    "glob": "^7.1.1",
    "howler": "^2.0.3",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "nan": "^2.1.0",
    "nconf": "^0.7.2",
    "node-schedule": "^1.2.5",
    "opener": "^1.4.3",
    "pusher-js": "^4.1.0",
    "sqlite3": "^3.1.8",
    "unirest": "^0.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^4.0.2",
    "chai-as-promised": "^6.0.0",
    "electron": "^1.8.3",
    "electron-builder": "^20.8.0",
    "electron-builder-squirrel-windows": "^20.9.0",
    "electron-installer-dmg": "^0.2.1",
    "electron-packager": "^5.1.1",
    "mocha": "^3.2.0",
    "spectron": "^3.0.0",
    "xo": "^0.10.0"
  },
  "xo": {
    "esnext": true,
    "envs": [
      "node",
      "browser"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Try posting the contents of your package.json so people can tell what your dist script is actually doing, will help with debugging

Comment: Thank you @AlienHoboken, I've done that.

Answer (score 1):

The LSBackgroundOnly option in Mac apparently has this effect because it designates the app a background app and presumably no events are delivered to it.  Once I set it to false, the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you have given proper focus code:-

```
    app.focus({
        steal: true
      });
```